# scipy append all rows of one sparse matrix to another

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a numpy matrix and want to append another matrix to that.

The two matrices have the shapes:

```
m1.shape = (2777, 5902)  m2.shape = (695, 5902)
```

I want to append m2 to m1 so that the new matrix is of shape:

```
m_new.shape = (3472, 5902)
```

When I use numpy.append or numpy.concatenate I just get a new array with the two matrix in it and the shape (2,1).

Any one of you have an Idea how to get one big matrix out of the two?

Additional info: both are sparse matrices.

EDIT:
m1 looks like

```
(0, 1660)   0.444122811195
(0, 3562)   0.260868771714
(0, 4743)   0.288149437574
(0, 4985)   0.514889706991
(0, 5215)   0.272163636657
(0, 5721)   0.559006134727
(1, 555)    0.0992498400527
(1, 770)    0.133145289523
(1, 790)    0.0939044698233
(1, 1097)   0.259867567986
(1, 1285)   0.188836288168
(1, 1366)   0.24707459927
(1, 1499)   0.237997843516
(1, 1559)   0.120069347224
(1, 1701)   0.17660176488
(1, 1926)   0.185678520634
(1, 2177)   0.163066377369
(1, 2641)   0.079958199952
(1, 2937)   0.259867567986
(1, 3551)   0.198471489351
(1, 3562)   0.0926197593026
(1, 3593)   0.100537828805
(1, 4122)   0.198471489351
(1, 4538)   0.57162654484
(1, 4827)   0.105808609537
```

m2 looks like:

```
(0, 327)    0.0770581299315
  (0, 966)  0.309858753157
  (0, 1231) 0.286870892505
  (0, 1384) 0.281385698712
  (0, 1817) 0.204495931592
  (0, 2284) 0.182420951496
  (0, 2414) 0.114591086901
  (0, 2490) 0.261442040482
  (0, 3122) 0.321676138471
  (0, 3151) 0.286870892505
  (0, 4031) 0.172251612658
  (0, 5149) 0.25839783806
  (0, 5215) 0.125806303262
  (0, 5225) 0.336280781816
  (0, 5231) 0.135930403721
  (0, 5294) 0.145049459537
  (0, 5794) 0.20145172917
  (0, 5821) 0.224439589822
  (1, 327)  0.191031948626
  (1, 1171) 0.62081265022
```

Type of the matrices is:

```
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'> <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

SOLVED:

```
m_new = scipy.sparse.vstack((m1, m2))
```

did the trick

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should have told us these were `scipy sparse` right from the start - and tagged the question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry I edited the question accordingly if someone es is looking for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.vstack` in your case (or `numpy.hstack`, when matrices shapes are (x,y) and (x,z))

Example:

```
a = np.zeros((3,7))
b = np.zeros((46,7))
c = np.vstack((a,b))
print c.shape
#(49,7)
```

Comment: If I do that I get the following:

`[[ <2777x5902 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 54003 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
 [ <695x5902 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 12226 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]]`

which is not what I wanted as this is a new array with two matrixes inside but I want one matrix as an outcome.

Comment: worked when using scipy.sparse.vstack instead of numpy vstack

Answer (score -2):

You can use `concatenate` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
m_new = np.concatenate((m1, m2))
```

For example,

```
a = np.zeros((5, 3))
b = np.zeros((4, 3))
print np.concatenate((a, b)).shape
# (9, 3)
```

That still works if you use matrices instead of arrays:

```
print np.concatenate((np.matrix(a), np.matrix(b))).shape
# (9, 3)
```

Comment: When I do that I get an the following ValueError
`ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated`

Comment: @d.a.d.a Then, it seems that one of your arrays does not have the shape you mention

Comment: @d.a.d.a Are you sure that you put the two arrays/matrices into a tuple `np.concatenate((m1, m2))`? Note the double set of parenthesis.

Comment: yes my code is `cross_val_matrix = np.concatenate((train_matrix, test_matrix))` and the shapes of train and test matrix is like m1 and m2 mentioned in the question

Comment: @d.a.d.a strange ... if you copy/paste the example I wrote down (`a = np.zeros((5, 3)); ...` does it work? what do you see if you do a `print type(train_matrix), type(test_matrix)`?

Comment: worked when using scipy.sparse.vstack instead of numpy vstack

Comment: @d.a.d.a makes more sense ... these were not numpy arrays ... glad you found a solution

Comment: Thanks for your help :-)